# How to create a new json field from another json key vaues with python?

Tags: python, json

I get lat and long from RESTful API. I need to craete new json field from another json fields.

I coded as below:

```
def collect_data():
  data = requests.get(url = URL).json() 
  del data['positions'][1]
  my_dict={}
  my_dict["satlatitude"]= data["positions"][0]["satlatitude"]
  my_dict["satlongitude"]= data["positions"][0]["satlongitude"]


  new_data = json.dumps(my_dict)
  new_data2 = {'geo' : {"lat": new_data["satlatitude"][0], "lon": new_data["satlatitude"][0]}} 
  es.index(index='satellitepositions', doc_type='satelitepos', body=new_data2)



schedule.every(10).seconds.do(collect_data)

while True:
  schedule.run_pending()
  time.sleep(1)
```

I don't get what I expect. What I need is:
   new_data2 = {'geo' : {"lat":satlatitude , "lon": satlongitude}}
   This satlatitude  and satlongitude should come from data. I'm confusing how to extract the fields
   from json documet.
   Can someone help me to solve this?

RESTful data sample:
   Json documet: {'info': {'satname': 'SPACE STATION', 'satid': 25544,
  'transactionscount': 0}, 'positions': [{'satlatitude': 28.89539607,
  'satlongitude': 90.44547739, 'sataltitude': 420.36, 'azimuth': 12.46,
   'elevation': -52.81, 'ra': 215.55022984, 'dec': -5.00234017, 'timestamp':
   1591196844, 'eclipsed': True}]}

new_data2 = {'geo' : {"lat":28.89539607 , "lon": 90.44547739,}}

But these values should change by each time.

Comment: can you provide an example of the data returned by the requests query?

It's hard to help you without understanding the data you're operating on.

Comment: Yes I will give

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue stems from this line :

```py
new_data = json.dumps(my_dict)
```

When you do this, you dump your dict to a string. You can no longer index it by dict keys, it's a string.

But you still try later to index it by key :

```py
new_data["satlatitude"][0]
```

This will crash. `new_data` is a string.

Do not juse `json.dumps`. I believe you don't need to serialize your data back to JSON, the elasticsearch library does this for you.

#### Solution :

Here's solution that (should be) working :

```py
data = requests.get(URL).json() 

new_data = {'geo':{'lat':data['positions'][0]['satlatitude'],
                   'lon':data['positions'][0]['satlongitude']}}

es.index(index='satellitepositions', doc_type='satelitepos', body=new_data)
```

Not that this has no validation that the requests has correctly returned, or that the data within conforms to your expectations. These should be checked if you want  your code to be robust.

Comment: But how do I create the 'geo' field with the values of lat and long?

Comment: I need to make this fields to create the index

Comment: I get this error  TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Fixed it and tested it.

Comment: I get following error, I know it's not because of this, but it's about Elasticsearch. If you familiar with ES can you help me? My error is : RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'field must be either [lat], [lon] or [geohash]'). If need i can update my question

Comment: Your answer isn't match with my mapping in ES.